# もんだと after する verb meaning

Tags: meaning

I found a sentence:

> キップを連想する**もんだと**思うが

What does mean? I found it could mean 揉う but I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Isn't it もん + だ (informal です) + と思う？

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43127/9831