# Why is もの used in 「無駄に使ってしまうもの」 (instead of こと)?

Tags: particle-こと

In

> お金というものはあったらあったで**無駄に使ってしまうもの**だ。
>
> Money is something that when you have it, you end up wasting it.

the phrase 「無駄に使ってしまう」 ("used towards waste!") is used to modify もの。

**Question:** Isn't "the act of using money wastefully" an abstract sort of thing? If so, shouldn't こと be used here in place of もの？

Comment: 無駄に使ってしまうこと is like 'the act of using wastefully'. What もの refers to is the very tangible お金

Comment: Does this answer your question? [which meaning does ものだ have here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82549) / [The meanings of ものだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/5010) / [What would be the function of the というものだ in this context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82293/5010)

Comment: Note that if you say お金というものは無駄に使ってしまうことだ it means "You SHOULD use money wastefully"

  

See https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/05/23/jlptn2-grammar-kotoda/

Answer (score 2):

You are right in the sense that, to refer to the act of wasting money, one would use こと. For example, お金を無駄に使ってしまう事がよくある.

In this instance, it's an idiom ...というものは....ものだ. It's used to describe the general belief of the speaker about things.

E.g.

```
お金というものはあったらあったで無駄に使ってしまうものだ
親というものは子供をどこまでも信じるものだ
やる気というものは、追い込まれると自然と湧いてくるものだ
お金の無駄使いというものは、なかなかやめられないものだ
```

I think もの is used because you are trying to put a concept into a concrete group to which you can assign a characteristic. Hence, you can use it for very abstract things like `やり場のない怒りというものは、人を貧しくするものだ`.

Comment: ものだ isn’t acting as a pkk look ace holder for a noun the way the question implies

Comment: In 「やり場のない」, is の acting as が, as per [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4346/difference-between-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%EF%BD%9E-and-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)?

Comment: @George I guess so, yeah. Compared to やり場がない怒り, の creates the impression that usually 怒り have corresponding やり場 as a general principle, but these special ones don’t. E.g. 縞々シャツのかかってない家 sounds weird because 縞々シャツ　is too specific/rare to be a general thing, whereas シマシマシャツがかかってない家 is fine

Comment: @EnnoShioji What do you mean by "シマシマシャツがかかってない家"? I'm parsing it as a "house which doesn't wear striped shirts", which I'm pretty sure is not what it actually means :]

Comment: かかっている in this context means, it's visible from the window hanging from a curtain rail or something @George