# Interpretation of もの in ヒーローとは常にピンチを壊していくもの

Tags: grammar, usage

> ヒーローとは常にピンチを壊していく**もの**!

I'm really skeptical about this. The fact とは is used makes me think that もの here means "someone" and the fact that だ is used makes me think he is stating some fact. Which one is it?

Comment: Related/dup https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43127/45489

Answer (score 1):

I assume (from the question) you understand it as a kind of contraction of

> ヒーローとは常にピンチを壊していくもの**だ**!

which is correct. It is an instance of 体言止め. E.g., see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/45489).

Practically, it is better to consider V+ものだ as an idiom, mentioned in [the following definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%89%A9_%28%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%29/#jn-219726).

> ５ 他の語句を受けて、その語句の内容を体言化する形式名詞。
>
> ㋒（「…するものだ」の形で）それが当然であるという気持ちを示す。「先輩の忠告は聞く―だ」「困ったときは助け合う―だ」

The もの is a nominalizer for the preceding sentence, to mean ***Subj.* is supposed to V**.

That said, it is not impossible to think もの is an replacement for *someone* and translate it as 'A here is someone who...'.