# interpretation of this もんだ

Tags: grammar

悪魔も理解できんもんは 怖がる**もん**だ does this もの mean thing as in "the **thing** that devils are afraid of, are the things that they dont understand"
Or is there something im missing?

Comment: I think you answered yourself xD

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43127/9831

Comment: The first もん after 理解できん is just "thing", but もん(だ) at the end of the sentence is different. "(**It's generally the case that**) even devils are afraid of **things** that are not understandable". See [this](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-mono-da-mono-janai-meaning/), too.