Where can I read more about もの?
I read a sentence that drinks make you fat:

飲み物は太るものだ

I don't understand how the particle もの affects the verb here, or if it even acts like a particle.
Any clarification and pointing to resources on this grammar would be much appreciated.

That もの indicates general tendencies. See option 2) in this link: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43127/7944
